# jQuery mobile CSS and data-attribute issues

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, custom-data-attribute

I'm using jQuery Mobile in a project and i'm not sure about how to handle some data-attributes CSS overrides.

For example, when i use data-attributes like `data-role="page"` to create page transitions, it overrides some of my CSS rules, applying its own. I'm not quite familiar with data-attributes yet...

I could use (a lot of) `!important` declarations but we know it might led to problems and clutter etc and therefore it should be avoided.

Any suggestions on how to deal with that?

Comment: you can use the jQM theme roller to create your own theme: http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/

Comment: nice editor! i'd prefer (in the project i'm working on right now) to use a code editor though.

Comment: no, you use the themeroller once to create CSS files for the look and feel you want. Then you include the CSS in your project and use your code editor like normal. In this way all the jQM widgets will be styled with your colors, rounding, shadowing, etc.